# Why my collider is triggered to many times?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]
I have a gameobject that boost my player up when i collide with it.I realised that the collider is activated way to many times.I did a debug.log on TriggerEnter function and i see that when i collide with bottom of the collider,it activates 5-7 times(it's like going up and collideing again i think),if i collide on top it activates 2-3 times.But how do i repair it to activate only one time?
P.S.The player's box colider is not set on trigger but the booster's is.

Code for Boost:

```
public void Boost()
{
    gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false; //to not collide random with objects when flying
    rb.AddForce(Booster.transform.up * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse);      
    StartCoroutine(waitForSecond(4f));//after for seconds enable it again
    //efect
}
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{       
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Booster") )
    {
        Boost();
    }      
}
```

Comment: Hey, tell me one thing, should your booster object be disabled after our player get boosted?

Comment: Because if this is the case, you can disable the object when your player collide the Booster object

Comment: @Ankit no sorry i don't want to disable it ,if there are no solution i will..

Comment: How many colliders are on objects? It can be called multiple times if multiple colliders are triggered.

Comment: It has only a box collider2D

Comment: You could print the other game object name to show who is triggering the event.
Does your player have several colliders ? If so, they should be children of your rigidbody or on the same GameObject

Comment: I resolved it, it was a problem with other script, my foult